# How can I successfully install and import the "adafruit_servokit" python library using Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, nvidia-jetson-nano, adafruit-circuitpython

I am trying to control motors using the  PCF9685 Servo Controller on the Jetson Nano. When I try to run

```
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit
```

I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adafruit_servokit'
```

I ran

```
sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-servokit
```

but this did not help; specifically, I get an error when it reaches

```
collecting Adafruit-Blinka - No matching distribution found for Adafruit-Blinka>=7.0.0 (from adafruit-circuitpython-servokit)
```

I have also tried installing Adafruit-Blinka separately using

```
sudo pip3 install Adafruit-Blinka
```

which appeared to have run successfully; however, I'm still getting the above error.